# PHP - download string as txt file also adds current page HTML to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a string that I am forcing download of as txt file on submit of a form, but it adds current page's HTML before and after the string in the txt file.

PHP:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['txt_submit'] ) ) {
    $arr = array('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com');

    $string = implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
    
    header ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=emails.txt');

    echo $string;
}
```

The HTML is not random, it is existent on the page on which I am running this PHP code.

The txt that downloads looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    ...
    </div>

abc@abc.com
xyz@xyz.com

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate txt file" name="txt_submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't put my PHP code before everything else because I am doing this on Wordpress in an admin menu page of a custom plugin, so this code is already inside the admin_menu action hook.

Comment: You should read the Wordpress documentation to find out how to properly trigger a file download.

Comment: Perhaps try adding it to the `admin_init` hook instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the download before everything else, and use exit(); after the echo, to prevent HTML from being in output.

Comment: I can't load my code before everything else because I am doing this on Wordpress in an admin menu page of a custom plugin, so this code is already inside the `admin_menu` action hook.

Comment: You can probably clear the output with `ob_end_clean();`. This requires `ob_start();` before everything else.

Comment: I added `ob_start();` before echo and `ob_end_clean();` after echo and it didn't work.